# Navigation problem (with a back button) in an Android app

Tags: android, navigation

Here is a navigation problem I am having within an Android app.
I must be missing something very basic, but can't see what.
Let's hope a new eye will spot the issue.

The app has three activities: MainActivity, FirstActivity, and SecondActivity.

And the navigation is meant to go like this:

MainActivity <-> FirstActivity <-> SecondActivity

In other words back-and-forth between MainActivity and FirstActivity an also
back-and-forth between FirstActivity and SecondActivity.
But with no direct path between MainActivity and SecondActivity.

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml supposed to translate what I wrote above:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:parentActivityName=".FirstActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <activity
        android:name=".FirstActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Now running the app the problem is this:

When I am in the SecondActivity and push the Up button, I expect to go back to the FirstActivity.

But instead I see some flickering, then a black screen and finally the app goes to the MainActivity.

What is going on?

Here is some more detail about the situation.

This is the code for *SecondActivity*:

```
package me.soft.myapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)
    }
}
```

And this is where *SecondActivity* is fired up inside *FirstActivity*:

```
val axBtn = Button(this)
......
axBtn.setOnClickListener {
    val axIntent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java).apply {
    }
    startActivity(axIntent)
}
```

Comment: Can you add ```SecondActivity``` too?

Comment: Looks like your app might be crashing due to some reason. kindly share the code that you have done for navigation.

Comment: I edited the post and just added some information, please have a look,

Comment: Agree looks like crash, do you see any exception in logcat?

Comment: Well, the app does not exactly stop; so I would not call it a crash. It just ends up in the MainActivity when I expect it to end up in the FirstActivity. I don't see anything in logcat, but I am not always sure how to properly look at logcat.

Comment: @Michel are you creating button axBtn  programmatically or its part of XML?

Comment: Yes  programmatically.